# Lua - how to add a path variable in OSX

Tags: lua, environment-variables

Can someone list the steps I would need to take to put a lua file (theclass.lua) somewhere on my system so that I can do this:

```
require 'theclass'
```

and the compiler will find it without having to copy theclass into every directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of places you may put it is part if the error message you receive:

```
~ e$ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require 'theclass'
stdin:1: module 'theclass' not found:
no field package.preload['theclass']
no file './theclass.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/theclass.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/theclass/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/theclass.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/theclass/init.lua'
no file './theclass.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/theclass.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'require'
stdin:1: in main chunk
[C]: ?
>
```

Lua consults at least three places for the list of directories to search:

The C `LUA_PATH` in the configuration header

The Lua global `LUA_PATH`

The environment variable `LUA_PATH`

See [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html)

Comment: Actually, Lua uses `package.path`, whose default value comes from the environment variable `LUA_PATH` if it is set. Lua never looks at the global variable `LUA_PATH`.

Comment: Oh. PiL 1 at http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html must be obsolete: "To determine its path, require first checks the global variable LUA_PATH." I see this is fixed in section 15.1 of my paper copy of PiL 2. Thanks, Luiz!

Comment: The online version of PiL is for Lua 5.0, which did use the global variable `LUA_PATH`. Compare http://www.lua.org/source/5.0/src_lib_lbaselib.c.html#getpath with http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/loadlib.c.html#setpath .